# Using JPA on startup singleton

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic12c, jpa-2.1

I want to access database using JPA 2.1 eclipselink on startup. When it runs, I get login successful in the console log but it throws table or view does not exist. However, if I call my dao in servlet through rest service, everything runs fine. Am I missing something?

```java
public abstract class BaseDao {
   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myUnit")
   protected EntityManager em;
   public void create(Object entity);
   public Ojbect get();
}

@Stateless
public class MyDaoService extends BaseDao {
   @Override
   public void create(Object entity) {
      this.em.persit(entity);
   }
   // ...
}

@Singleton
@Startup
public class MySingleton{
   @EJB
   private MyDaoService service;
   @Schedule(hours="*", minutes="*", seconds="*/30")
   public void doSomething() {
      MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();//assumed I have entity object
      entity.setFirstName("firstName");
      entity.setLastName("lastName");
      service.create(entity); // >>>Table or view does not exist exception
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem.

> If a JEE and JTA managed entity manager is used, specifying a proxy user and password can be more difficult, as the entity manager and JDBC connection is not under the applications control. The persistence unit properties can still be specified on an EntityManager object as long as this is done before establishing a database connection. [EclipseLink Solutions Guide for EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/solutions/oracledb002.htm)

EDIT: Make sure you set it before each transaction

Answer (score 0):

The doSomething would need a @PostConstruct if you want it to be called after your bean is initialized. Also if you have dependencies you need to be available before that bean is initialized then you can use [@DependsOn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/DependsOn.html)

Comment: EDITED: I have @Schedule annotation which runs every 30 seconds and i dont think there are any dependencies. My data source uses proxy authentication and since the program runs automatically and doesn't have user associate with it. I think that's the problem. I dont know if there is a way to inject user name and password to the entityManager